# Getting a Class to recognise and loop through its own Properties

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I'm not sure if the heading of this question is even going to make sense to anyone.

Each class in my code represents a table in a SQL server database, and the class properties are the data fields.  I have several methods that are common to most of the classes I write, namely Populate, Update, Save etc.  Nothing new there so far.

However, during the development cycle and even after implementation of my software, it is relatively common for the need to arise to add an additional field in one of tables, and hence an additional property in the corresponding class.  This is turn means I have to go through the Populate, Update, Save methods to add the new field, for example :-

```
private void Save()
{
   SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(connString);
   linkToDB.Open();
   string sqlText = "INSERT INTO table (ID, Field1, Field2) VALUES (@ID, @Field1, @Field2);";
   SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlText, linkToDB);
   sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this._id;
   sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Field1",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this._field1;
   sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@Field2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this._field2;
   sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
   linkToDB.Close();
   linkToDB.Dispose();
}
```

Image the need arises to add a new field to this my class and hence the SAVE method above needs the sqlText to be amended, the sqlCom to have a new parameter added.  The same changes need to be made to my UPDATE and POPULATE methods and any others that have a complete set of parameters corresponding to the Class properties.

So my question is this . . .

Is there a way to have a Class recognise and iterate through its own properties, and create parameters of the correct type for each one.  I did start some code (which I know does not compile) but I am stuck.  Here is where I got up to.

```
private void Populate()
{
   SQLExpress exp = new SQLExpress();
   using (SqlConnection linkToDB = exp.DatabaseConnection)
   {
      string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM " + this._table + " WHERE ID = @ID;";
      SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlText, linkToDB);
      linkToDB.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
      {
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             Type type = this.GetType();
             foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
             {
                 string propName = propertyInfo.Name;
                 Type propType = propertyInfo.GetType();

                 //this.propName = (propType)reader[propName];
                 //Type propType = propertyInfo.GetType();                            
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is anyone able to offer any advice how I might achieve my coding goals here?  Should I be going about this a completely different way perhaps?  Or is what I am trying to achieve simply not possible?

Comment: What you try to accomplish here is known as Object-Relational Mapping. Instead of trying to bake something on your own, why don't you use any of the available frameworks people develop for years? nHibernate, Entity Framework, linq2Sql, you-name-it will save your time and offer features you even don't realize they exist but you will need them in near future.

Comment: It sounds like you plan on adding the additional fields to the class as well. If this is the case - Why not amend the code at the same time? Why not use EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. Once you have the PropertyInfo[] you can read (or write) the values of that property:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
{
  var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(this);
  propertyInfo.SetValue(this, new_value);
}
```

that's all.
BTW like other say, what you're try to do is not so easy as it seems and there are a lot of tools that already do this kind of thinks: they are ORM.
Take a look at EntityFramework or at NHibernate.

Comment: propertyInfo.SetValue(this, value);
does not compile, its telling me no constructor has 2 arguments!

Comment: Yep, sorry the third parameter is used for indexed properties. null is ok in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of 1 to 1 CRUD operations, I prefer using an ORM.  It handles all the mappings and even can update your models (classes) when adding new fields to the database automatically.

Have you explored this as an option, perhaps [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef)?  There are a lot of different ORMs out there -- just do a quick search.

Good luck.